# multi package makefile example for go

Tags: makefile, go

I'm trying to setup a multi package go project something like

./main.go

./subpackage1/sub1_1.go

./subpackage1/sub1_2.go

./subpackage2/sub2_1.go

./subpackage2/sub2_2.go

where main.go imports both subpackage1 and subpackage2. And subpackage2 imports subpackage1.

Ive been looking around for go makefile examples but I can't find anything that supports this kind of set-up. Any idea?

Answer (score 17):

Install [godag](http://code.google.com/p/godag/) then run:

`gd -o myapp`

It will automatically build a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) of all the dependencies in your `src/` directory, then compile and link each package in the proper order.

Much easier than manually maintaining a Makefile, especially since $(GOROOT)/src/Make.* has changed in recent versions of Go (there is no longer a Make.$(GOARCH)). Also useful:

`gd clean` removes object files.

`gd -test` runs your automated tests (see testing package).

`gd -dot=myapp.dot` generates a graph of your package imports you can visualize using GraphViz.

Comment: Me, too, have found no saner way to build multiple package than using build tools like `gd`.

Comment: Not since ghc --make have I seen such a simple compile process.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work

```
# Makefile
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)
all:main
main:main.$O
    $(LD) -Lsubpackage1/_obj -Lsubpackage2/_obj -o $@ $^
%.$O:%.go  subpackage1 subpackage2
    $(GC) -Isubpackage1/_obj -Isubpackage2/_obj -o $@ $^
subpackage1:
    $(MAKE) -C subpackage1
subpackage2:
    $(MAKE) -C subpackage2
.PHONY:subpackage1 subpackage2

# subpackage1/Makefile
TARG=subpackage1
GOFILES=sub1_1.go sub1_2.go
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg

# subpackage2/Makefile
TARG=subpackage2
GOFILES=sub2_1.go sub2_2.go
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
GC+=-I../subpackage1/_obj
LD+=-L../subpackage1/_obj
sub2_1.$O sub2_2.$O:subpackage1
subpackage1:
    $(MAKE) -C ../subpackage1
.PHONY:subpackage1
```

If you don't install the subpackages you need to explicitly set the include path. The supplied makefile Make.pkg is mainly to build packages, which is why it's only included in the subpackage makefile.

Comment: `$(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)` is the old way to do it and doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

[hello world with a Makefile and a test](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/b96c91e16c466cc4/) (Googles Groupes : golang-nuts)

Comment: the above uses `$(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)` which is the old way to do it and doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Check out https://github.com/banthar/Go-SDL which is an actively maintained multi-package go project using Makefiles.

I notice some of these the answers use the obsolete `Make.$(GOARCH)` include. So hopefully the above link will be stabler than trying to stay on top of Google's changing API in an answer here.

Comment: Um, it doesn't keep dependencies, and uses recursive make, which wouldn't really work for large project (though no large project is written in go yet AFAIK).

Comment: True about dependencies. Recursive Make looks to me like the only way to use go's Make.cmd or Make.pkg though. So far I'm having luck using recursive Make in a project of my own, although it's still pretty young. I do dependency management manually.

Comment: recursive make are the only sane way to use Make for multi-package builds, and in fact it's recommended by the documentation. However it's an horrible way to do that, inefficient and problematic. Make itself is broken, I think go should include `gd` as a standard way to make go projects. It's really essential to have it as a part of the language.